# Duda de código procedimiento almacenado para crear un insert en la tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure

He tenido problemas con este código ya que no me genera el procedimiento almacenado; lo estoy ejecutando en phpmyadmin y me tira el error:

```
" MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 7"
```

¿Cómo puedo modificar este código para crear un insert en la tabla?

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertarPro(
    nom varchar(150),
    pre decimal(18,2),
    img varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE cod int;
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Cod_producto),0)+1 INTO cod FROM producto;
INSERT INTO producto VALUES (cod,nom,pre,img);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que para darle valor a una variable debes usar `set`.

> DELIMITER //
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertarPro(nom varchar(150), pre decimal(18,2),
>   img varchar(100)) BEGIN   DECLARE cod INT DEFAULT 0;
>   set cod =
>   (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Cod_producto),0)+1 FROM producto);
>
> INSERT INTO producto VALUES (cod,nom,pre,img); END//
>
> DELIMITER ;

Comment: fijate que he ejecutado tal y como me lo sugeriste pero me sigue dando el mismo error, no se que podra ser

Comment: @Oryon elimina el "DECLARE COD INT;"

Comment: fijate que al ejecutar sin el declare cod int me tira este error: " MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1193 - Desconocida variable de sistema 'cod'"

Comment: @Oryon hice un cambio en la respuesta, prueba nuevamente